# Fatfree Framework error 404 on every route

Tags: php, .htaccess, fat-free-framework

This is working localy on my WAMP server, but when I tried to use it on my host it always gets an error:

```
HTTP 404 (GET /)

• teste/index.php:17 Base->run()
```

You can see the error here: http://rafaelmsantos.com/teste/

I don't have a clue whats going on, I've tried different .htaccess but it display always the same error.

**.htaccess**

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(lib|tmp)\/|\.(ini)$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

**config.ini**

```
[globals]

AUTOLOAD=public/pages/

DB.dns="mysql:host=localhost; dbname=lod; port=3306;"
DB.user="root"
DB.password=""

DEBUG=3
UI=assets/
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

$lod = require('lib/base.php');
$lod->config('config.ini');


// HELPERS DEVELOPED BY ME
require_once 'helpers/base_helper.php';

//*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//*                             PÁGINAS                             */
//*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
$lod->route('GET /', 'PagesController->index');
$lod->route('GET /project/@page', 'PagesController->index');


$lod->run();
```

**And my folder structure:**

[image: Print Screen of folder structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to autoload in another way,

insted of `AUTOLOAD=public/pages/` on config.ini, I had to use `$lod->set('AUTOLOAD','public/pages/');` after the `require_once` and before the routes.

Answer (score 2):

try to set the RewriteBase in your .htaccess (as the comment above said):

```
RewriteBase /teste/
```